# Xcode not letting me ctrl drag to add outlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add an action to my swift file from ctrl dragging from the storyboard. This doesn't seem to be working for my Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer. Why could this be?

[image: not working]

Comment: Have you tried this on a new project? It works for me. The most likely answer is that you're dragging to the wrong view controller.

Comment: @dylanthelion that's probably it. Do you need a new 'viewcontroller.swift' for every viewcontroller screen you add?

Comment: Every UIViewController you add to your Storyboard has an assigned class (the page-looking navigator to the left of the Shield-Looking navigator, in the  upper-left, will have that class). You can only drag outlets, if the class indicated there matches the class of the .swift file you are dragging to. The default is UIViewController.swift. If you've added a custom UIViewController class, you need to change the class of the ViewController  in your Storyboard.

Comment: Just did that and it works thanks for the help @dylanthelion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to create outlet in other view controller, which is is not a super class of controller. Check in identity inspector. Select [automatic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVsTo.png)  from assistant window.
[image: automatic]

Comment: I have connected ViewController and Layout (in inspector mode). In auutomatic mode. Doesn't work

Comment: doesn't help. problem is i messed with ctrl key shortcuts, after the conflict, the system took the xcode outlet dragging function off

Comment: although i'm sure i was selecting my ViewController file when switching to assistant editor mode. the file shows the correct class name but the class definition showed internal class xViewController: UIVIewController. when i switched to automatic, everything worked normally!